# Changed behavior in handoff between CiviContribut and PayPal

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

We're encountering a problematic changed behavior in the CiviContribute module when it hands an online contribution over to PayPal Standard for payment.

The purchase description used to be like this:

Online Contribution: Sponsor a Child

which made it very easy for our treasurer to assign the payment accordingly.

The purchase description now appears like this:

1092-4219-Sponsor a Chil

where the first number is the contact ID and the second is Civi's internal  contribution ID -- neither of which is very useful to the treasurer.  Meanwhile the purchase purpose is truncated making it harder to figure out where to assign the payment in the back end accounting.

We are running Civi 4.7.14 in a Wordpress CMS.  It looks like the changed behavior might have begun when we upgraded from 4.6.X to 4.7.14.

Questions:

a.  Is this a "feature" or a "bug"?

b.  Is there a setting or template that we can adjust to get back to the original behavior or otherwise control the product description that is handed to PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

It's documented and resolved in JIRA

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19863